# Irrelevant Line on nav bar Menu Boostrap

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

[This is my Full screen menu on 1080p display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdFup.png)

[This is Menu on 720p display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Udt7z.png)

The problem is i am experiencing An extra line on 720P display can anyone tell why it is happening? Here is my code

```
  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar1">

    <ul id="main" class="nav nav-tabs nav-justified" style="background-color: #F7F7F7;color:white">
      <?php
              $pages = array('home.php');
              if(in_array($pageName,$pages)){
                 $mainActive = 'active';
                 $inactive='';
                 $color='';
              }
              else
              {
                $mainActive = ''; 
                $inactive='inactive';
                $color='style="color:white"';
              }
            ?>
      <li class="<?php echo $mainActive?>" style="border-right:1px solid;border-radius: 5px;background-color: #31b0d5;"><a class="<?php echo $inactive?>" href="home.php" <?php echo $color; ?>>Home</a></li>
 <?php
              $pages = array('calendar.php');
              if(in_array($pageName,$pages)){
                $mainActive = 'active';
                $inactive='';
                $color='';
              }
              else
              {
                $mainActive = '';
                $inactive='inactive';
                $color='style="color:white"';
              }
      ?> 

      <li class="<?php echo $mainActive; ?>" style="border-right:1px solid;border-radius: 5px;background-color: #31b0d5;"><a class="<?php echo $inactive?>" href="calendar.php" <?php echo $color; ?>>My Schedules</a></li>
// and so on all other menu items have similar styling   
</ul>
</div>
```

Comment: This looks more like a CSS issue than a HTML one. Can you edit your question include both the CSS and the actual HTML output, not the PHP spaghetti

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the anchor text becomes multi-line, you may set the text vertically middle align the `<li>` block.

I add the below css:

```
.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li {
  vertical-align: middle;
}

.nav-tabs.nav-justified>li>a {
  border: 0!important;
}
```

You may need to modify your php as well, I changed the `<li>` to `background-color: white` when it is active.

Here's the jsfiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/urmf4ejf/

Comment: Thanks You are a like Saver :)